# Have an image link from iMDB api, how can I change it's size pyton

Tags: python, api, imdb

I am trying to work with IMDb API. My code thus far is

```
import http.client
import json
import requests

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("imdb-api.com", 443)
payload = ''
headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/95.0'}
conn.request("GET", "https://imdb-api.com/en/API/MostPopularMovies/<API_Key>",headers=headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
convertedDict = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
imagepath = r'venv/files/image.jpeg'
req = requests.get(convertedDict['items'][0]['image'], headers=headers)

with open(imagepath, 'wb') as file:
   file.write(req.content)
```

This allows me to download the image of the first popular movie, however, the image size is really small. This is the link that I am downloading. I know that if I get rid of everything after @ the image will become a lot larger. Is there a way to edit the link such that I can drop everything after @ and even edit the numbers after UX with code?
Everything I try to do with string or URL operations give's me an error

https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZWMyYzFjYTYtNTRjYi00OGExLWE2YzgtOGRmYjAxZTU3NzBiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzQ0MzA0NTM@._V1_UX128_CR0,3,128,176_AL_.jpg

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation

(code example below)

Here's how to get a bigger image of the size you want. Given this URL,

```
 https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZWMyYzFjYTYtNTRjYi00OGExLWE2YzgtOGRmYjAxZTU3NzBiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzQ0MzA0NTM@._V1_UX128_CR0,3,128,176_AL_.jpg
```

There's a substring of it:

```
 UX128_CR0,3,128,176
```

This has three important parts:

1. The first 128 resizes the image by width, keeping ratio
2. The second 128 controls the container width that the image appears in
3. 176 controls the container height that the image appears in.

So, we can view the structure like this:

```
 UX<image_width>_CR0,3,<container_width>,<container_height>
```

As an example, to double the image size:

```
 UX256_CR0,3,256,352_AL_.jpg
```

(Click here to see: [https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZWMyYzFjYTYtNTRjYi00OGExLWE2YzgtOGRmYjAxZTU3NzBiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzQ0MzA0NTM@.*V1_UX256_CR0,3,256,352_AL*.jpg](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZWMyYzFjYTYtNTRjYi00OGExLWE2YzgtOGRmYjAxZTU3NzBiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzQ0MzA0NTM@._V1_UX256_CR0,3,256,352_AL_.jpg)

### Update: Example of how you might do it in Python.

```
import re

resize_factor = 2 # Image size multiple
url = "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZWMyYzFjYTYtNTRjYi00OGExLWE2YzgtOGRmYjAxZTU3NzBiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzQ0MzA0NTM@._V1_UX128_CR0,3,128,176_AL_.jpg"

#
# resize_factor : Image size multiplier (e.g., resize_factor = 2 doubles the image size, positive integer only)
# url : full URL of the image
# return : string of the new URL
#

def getURL(resize_factor, url):

    # Regex for pattern matching relevant parts of the URL
    p = re.compile(".*UX([0-9]*)_CR0,([0-9]*),([0-9]*),([0-9]*).*") 
    match = p.search(url)
    
    if match:
        # Get the image dimensions from the URL
        img_width = str(int(match.group(1)) * resize_factor)
        container_width = str(int(match.group(3)) * resize_factor)
        container_height = str(int (match.group(4)) * resize_factor)
    
        # Change the image dimensions
        result = re.sub(r"(.*UX)([0-9]*)(.*)", r"\g<1>"+ img_width +"\g<3>", url)
        result = re.sub(r"(.*UX[0-9]*_CR0,[0-9]*,)([0-9]*)(.*)", r"\g<1>"+ img_width +"\g<3>", result)
        result = re.sub(r"(.*UX[0-9]*_CR0,[0-9]*,[0-9]*,)([0-9]*)(.*)", r"\g<1>"+ container_height +"\g<3>", result)
    
        return result
#
# Test
#

print (getURL(resize_factor,url))
```

Edit: Typo

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is this possible to do with code?

Comment: @Nemo I've updated my post. Hopefully it helps you a bit.

Comment: @Siege `CR` (crop) command requires 4 parameters: `x`, `y`, `w` and `h`.